# Is there any performance impact to have multiple Mongo databases?

Tags: mongodb, performance

We are currently working on an application using Mongo and we try to evaluate benefits and constraints on each differents architecture choices related to spreading data on multiple databases/collections or using a single shared one.

Is there any performance penalties between one single database with a lot of collections or many databases with less collections per database ?

From what I understand it does not seem to have any impact because sharding is done per collection basis but I would like some confirmations.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

By performance, I guess you mean read/write speed. Using multiple databases with fewer collections would definitely increase your read/write speed since each database can handle more read/write operations on the collections associated with them.

However, spreading data across databases this way I believe can bring about extra complexity to your project, depending on how your codebase is structured, it might introduce complexity to your application logic, things like backup and other admin database operations won't be straight forward, cross collection ad-hoc queries for collection that lives in different databases would be next to impossible.

If the goal of the architecture design is to ensure high read/write speed, you can still go with using a single DB that can be auto-scaled at the deployment level. I don't know much about it but I think [Replication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/index.html) is a MongoDB feature that can help you achieve such auto-scaling and if you are in for database-as-a-service, you should check out [MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas), auto-scaling is out of the box.

Comment: Yes, I mean read/write speed but also CPU and memory consumption. We are in process to transform our application to a multi-tenant one and basically isolation between databases is not a problem. We are wondering what is really the cost of having same amout of collections into a single database or split into many database.

Comment: What is the consequence of using a database on a resources point of view ? Does it reserve something ? Dedicated files ? Dedicated threads ? Increased memory or CPU consumption ? Increased size on disk ?

Comment: Like I said in the comment above, when using multiple databases, better CPU/Memory usage is a given. I’m not sure I understand these other consequences you mentioned; reserving something, dedicated files/threads. Maybe you can shed more light on that.

Comment: Thanks. By reserving "something" I mean that I would like to know what is the consequence of each choice on a resources point of view (CPU, memory, size on file system etc...). For example you say it is a better CPU/Memory usage but I do not why and how Mongo server manage server resources. I can imagine that creating a database create its own set of files in the server, consume a part of memory and CPU. Or perhaps it is still on a collection count basis and resources consumed still depends on collection count whatever the number of database.

Comment: Is there any technical documentation describing low level management ?